# Integration of apache shiro with java EE application

Tags: java, apache, authentication, shiro

I am currently building a web application and I have started integrating apache shiro to perform basic authentication. I have developed a custom JdbcRealm. And it seems to be fine.

My [Shiro.ini] file

```
[main]
jdbcRealm = com.sigmastream.yh.api.http.YhJdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[urls]
/yhrest/login/** = authcBasic
```

## Custom Jdbc Realm

```
public class YhJdbcRealm extends JdbcRealm
{
    public YhJdbcRealm()
    {
        this.dataSource = getDataSource();
        this.authenticationQuery = "SELECT password from users WHERE username = ?";
    }

    public BasicDataSource getDataSource()
    {
        String dbPath = AppProperties.getInstance().getConfig().getProperty("iot.web.admin.source.dbpath",
                "");
        String poolSize = AppProperties.getInstance().getConfig().getProperty("iot.db.connection.pool.size", "25");
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath);
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(poolSize));
        dataSource.setMaxActive(1);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        AuthenticationInfo info = super.doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);
        return info;
    }
}
```

I am using SQLite as database.I am expecting apache shiro to authenticate each request which comes in my application except login page.

I dont know where am I making a mistake in configuring apache shiro in my application. It would be appriciable If any one can provide some guidance or help.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

The only path that is protected is: `/yhrest/login/**`
I'm guessing that is your login page, so you probably want something like:
```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /yhrest/login

[urls]
/** = authcBasic
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct, I missed the entries for other URLs which are being bypassed from the authentication